How to link to another blender file with it's animations?
How do I link to a Blender file and it's animation(s), for example a ball with a bouncing animation and a rolling animation, and use it in another Blender file without breaking the link to the ball Blender file?

Animations are stored as "action" data blocs.
Link or Append Actions
If the object have actions in the blend file you link it from, the actions should be linked automatically since they are a child data of the object. Exactly the same way that when you link/append an object that also have materials and textures and whatnot, it will be linked/appended without you needing to do it manually.
However, if the animations were made in a different file than the one you linked the object from, you can always link or append them after, it will not break anything. You will find them in the blend file's "Actions" folder:

Using the Actions data
You can find them in the Dope Sheet editor set to Action mode:

You can also add them in the Non-Linear Animation editor. Use the menu Track to add a new track, then ⇧ ShiftA to add an action to the track:

It is likely that you already have an action open in the action editor or in the NLA, it depends on how you let things in the original file.
